# Print columns of second row

Tags: awk

What is wrong with this please?

```
awk 'FRN == 2 {print $7,"\t",$9,"\t",$11}' input > out
```

input is

```
56924.716851    0.003449                                                           
 word dog a house 1 ball     0.00679 +/-   0.00550 z  26800 points
```

I would like to print:

```
 0.00679   0.00550   26800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `FRN` with `FNR` or `NR`.

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)